# jQuery/JS - Count elements within element

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery or JS I need to count the amount of DIV elements inside my parent DIV called `cont`? I've seen similar questions here on StackOverflow and have tried the following.

```
<div class="b-load" id="cont">
    <div>
    <img src="page2.jpg" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="page3.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="page4.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
    <img src="page5.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>

function countPages() {
    var maindiv = document.getElementById('cont');
    var count = maindiv.getElementsByTagName('div').length;
    alert(count);
}
```

The child DIV's are dynamically produced, so I need to count them after the page has finished loading. The problem I have is the function I wrote counts 13 DIV's and in this example, there should only 4!! Any help gratefully received..

Comment: it shows 4 correctly - http://jsfiddle.net/QSurJ/

Comment: All I'm doing different is using [body onload="countPages()"]

Comment: I just changed getElementsByTagName('div') to getElementsByTagName('img') and I get the correct number but I'm still shocked that I get a different number than the fiddle example!!

Comment: maybe you have somewhere on your page a second element with `id=cont` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
console.log($("#cont div").length);
```

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: you are incorrect. If an #id is the first part of a selector, Jake's way is the fastest. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421782/performance-of-jquery-selector-with-context

Comment: @Interrobang That accepted answer in that thread shows that adding context improves performance. However, there is no mention of a `#foo div` selector in that question...

Comment: The accepted answer says that adding context improves performance except in the case of ID selectors, and a JSPerf link is provided in the thread as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
var maindiv = document.getElementById('cont');
var count = maindiv.children.length;
alert(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   var mainDiv = $('#cont');
   var childDivCount = mainDiv.find('div').length;
   });
```

By the way, this is jQuery's syntax (one of them anyways) for document ready. This will only fire after your page has completed loading.

Answer (score -1):

No need to use jQuery here. If you only need to know the amount of childElements, you can use `node.childElementCount`