# Count the number of buttons present inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to count number of buttons present inside a div in javascript?

```
<div id='maindiv'>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
    <button></button>
</div>
```

Comment: `var count = $('#maindiv button').length`  this will give you the count

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JS - Count elements within element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598286/jquery-js-count-elements-within-element)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many ways: 
Javascript: `document.querySelectorAll('#maindiv button')`

JQuery: `$('#maindiv button')`

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('#maindiv button')
console.log(buttons.length)
```

```html
<div id='maindiv'> <button></button> <button></button> <button></button> <button></button> <button></button> </div>
```

Comment: this will find all buttons not just the ones in the div!

Comment: :-) better and plain JS -> have a +1

Answer (score 3):

you can find all buttons inside div and get length of it

```js
$(function(){
  var count = $('#maindiv button').length;
  console.log(count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='maindiv'>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
  <button></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure js:

```js
const result = document.querySelectorAll('#maindiv button').length

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div id='maindiv'> 
  <button></button> <button></button> <button></button> <button></button> <button></button> 
</div>
```

or for all children:

```js
const result = document.getElementById('maindiv').children.length;

console.log(result)
```

```html
<div id='maindiv'> 
  <button></button> <button></button> <button></button> <button></button> <button></button> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(function(){
    var totalDiv = $('#maindiv').children('button').length;
    consloe.log(totalDiv)
});`