# jQuery context slows down search

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-selectors, jquery-context

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Performance of jQuery selector with context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421782/performance-of-jquery-selector-with-context)

In the [jQuery DOCS](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) it says

> By default, selectors perform their searches within the DOM starting
>   at the document root. However, an alternate context can be given for
>   the search by using the optional second parameter to the $() function.

Based on that my understanding is that a selection using a `context` passed in as the second parameter should be faster then the same selection without the `context` passed in. However I ran some tests and it seems as if this isn't the case, or at least isn't always the case.

To elaborate, I originally wanted to see if searching for multiple elements at once (`$("div1, #div2")`) was faster then searching for the two separately (`$("#div1") $("div2")`). I then decided to test it with the `context` and without to see how much faster it was with the `context`, but was surprised when it turned out that the `context` seemed to be slowing it down.

For example given the following basic HTML markup

```
<div id="testCnt">
    <div id="Div0"></div>
    <div id="Div1"></div>
    <div id="Div2"></div>
    <div id="Div3"></div>
    <div id="Div4"></div>
    <div id="Div5"></div>
    <div id="Div6"></div>
    <div id="Div7"></div>
    <div id="Div8"></div>
    <div id="Div9"></div>
</div>
```

And the following JavaScript (jQuery 1.8.2, and tested using FireBug)

```
$(function () {    
    var $dvCnt = $('#testCnt');
    var dvCnt = $dvCnt[0];

    console.time('Individual without cache');
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        $('#Div0').text('Test');
        $('#Div1').text('Test');
        $('#Div2').text('Test');
        $('#Div3').text('Test');
        $('#Div4').text('Test');
        $('#Div5').text('Test');
        $('#Div6').text('Test');
        $('#Div7').text('Test');
        $('#Div8').text('Test');
        $('#Div9').text('Test');

    }
    console.timeEnd('Individual without cache');

    console.time('Individual with $cache');
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        $('#Div0', $dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div1', $dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div2', $dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div3', $dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div4', $dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div5', $dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div6', $dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div7', $dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div8', $dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div9', $dvCnt).text('Test');

    }
    console.timeEnd('Individual with $cache');

    console.time('Individual with DOM cache');
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        $('#Div0', dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div1', dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div2', dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div3', dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div4', dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div5', dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div6', dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div7', dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div8', dvCnt).text('Test');
        $('#Div9', dvCnt).text('Test');

    }
    console.timeEnd('Individual with DOM cache');


    console.time('Multiple without cache');
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        $('#Div0,#Div1 ,#Div2 ,#Div3 ,#Div4 ,#Div5 ,#Div6, #Div7, #Div8, #Div9').text('Test');
    }
    console.timeEnd('Multiple without cache');

    console.time('Multiple with $cache');
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        $('#Div0,#Div1 ,#Div2 ,#Div3 ,#Div4 ,#Div5 ,#Div6, #Div7, #Div8, #Div9', $dvCnt).text('Test');
    }
    console.timeEnd('Multiple with $cache');

    console.time('Multiple with DOM cache');
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        $('#Div0,#Div1 ,#Div2 ,#Div3 ,#Div4 ,#Div5 ,#Div6, #Div7, #Div8, #Div9', dvCnt).text('Test');
    }
    console.timeEnd('Multiple with DOM cache');
});
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ehumic/3/edit)

I'm getting something like the following results

Individual without cache: 11490ms
Individual with $cache: 13315ms
Individual with DOM cache: 14487ms

Multiple without cache: 7557ms
Multiple with $cache: 7824ms
Multiple with DOM cache: 8589ms

Can someone shed some insight on whats going on? Specifically why the search is slowing down when the jQuery context is passed in?

*EDIT:*

Most of the anwsers here (as well as [Performance of jQuery selector with context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2421782/384985)) basically say that that either the DOM in this example is too small to really gain much or that selecting by `ID` is going to be fast regardless. I understand both points, the main point of my question is why would the `context` **slow** down the search, the size of the `DOM` shouldn't make a difference for that, and neither should the fact that searching by ID is already very fast.

[@pebble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1490904/pebbl) suggested that the reason that its slower is because jQuery can't use the native browser methods (`getElementByID`), this seems to make sense to me, but then why is it faster to search for multiple elements in one selection?

Anyway I dumped the tests into a [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/jquery-selection-with-context) adding cases to search by class and was again surprised to see that the search for multiple classes with a cache this time was the fastest.

Comment: This was discussed and answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421782/performance-of-jquery-selector-with-context

Comment: I'll take a look at that question. I did search before I asked but I guess I missed that one...

Comment: Your test uses a simple HTML structure and selecting elements by ID which is not where using context yields faster results. You want to use context when you know you might be selecting a large set of results that are within some containing element. Context is particularly useful when the DOM gets large and you are using generalized selectors, things like `[name="foobar"]` because this type of selector looks at every element to check for the existence of the `name` attribute. Long-story-short: context is no magic bullet but it has it's place.

Comment: @epascarello I had forgotten what the URL was.

Comment: Whoops I did not link in my previous comment [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com). That is better.

Comment: @Jasper I was just trying to test to see what's faster and was surprised that it actually made it slower, normally my DOM is a bit bigger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would imagine there are lots of situations where using context will slow things down, mainly because jQuery will try and use browser native methods where it can - rather than traverse the entire dom. One example of this would be using `document.getElementById` as in your example.

#### why the slow down?

`getElementById` only exists on the document object - you have no way of using this on a contextual element - i.e. `element.getElementById`. So my theory would be that jQuery first does the id request using `document.getElementById`, and then, if there is a context set - scans through the parents of each element to tell if any of them exist as children of the context - thereby slowing the process down.

#### Other examples of selectors that may be slow

You will also find other places where depending on the selector you are using you will get performance increases - all down to what methods jQuery can use to speed up it's work. For example:

```
$('.className');
```

Would most likely translate to using `getElementsByClassName` or any other native method offered to select by className, However:

```
$('.className .anotherClassName');
```

Wouldn't be able to use this *(as it has to take the relationship into account)* and would have to use a mixture of `querySelector` *(if it exists)* and or pure javascript logic to work things out.

Having a good knowledge of what native methods are available will help you optimise your jQuery queries.

#### Ways to optimise

If you wish to optimise using a context, I would imagine this would prove a faster query than without:

```
$('div', context);
```

This will be because `getElementsByTagName` has existed <del>since the dawn of time</del> for a while, and can be used in pure JavaScript directly on a DOM element. However if you are to do this, it may be quicker to do the following:

```
$().pushStack( context[0].getElementsByTagName('div') );
```

or

```
$( context[0].getElementsByTagName('div') );
```

Mainly because you cut down on the jQuery function calls, although this is much less succinct. Another thing to be aware of with regards to many of the popular JavaScript environments - calling a function without arguments is *a lot* faster than calling with.

A relatively unused method for optimising certain jQuery selectors is to use the jQuery `eq` pseudo selector - this can speed things up in a similar way to using `LIMIT 0,1` in SQL queries - for example:

```
$('h2 > a');
```

Would scan inside all H2s looking for A elements, however if you know from the start that there is only ever going to be one A tag within your H2s you can do this:

```
$('h2 > a:eq(0)');
```

Plus if you know there is only ever going to be one H2 - the logic is the same:

```
$('h2:eq(0) > a:eq(0)');
```

#### The difference between $().pushStack and $().add

In response to Jasper's comment here is the difference between the two functions:

**.add:**

```
function (a,b){var c=typeof a=="string"?p(a,b):p.makeArray(a&&a.nodeType?
[a]:a),d=p.merge(this.get(),c);return this.pushStack(bh(c[0])||bh(d[0])?
d:p.unique(d))}
```

**.pushStack:**

```
function (a,b,c){var d=p.merge(this.constructor(),a);return
d.prevObject=this,d.context=this.context,b==="find"?d.selector=this.selector
+(this.selector?" ":"")+c:b&&(d.selector=this.selector+"."+b+"("+c+")"),d}
```

The major difference is that `.add()` uses `.pushStack()` to acheive it's goals - add allows support for a lot more data types - even jQuery objects. Whereas `.pushStack` is only designed for DOM Elements, which makes it more optimal if that is what you are using :)

#### A quicker way to select by ID?

This is obvious, but I thought I'd put this here as sometimes things are missed - a quicker way to select an element by id would be to do the following:

```
$(document.getElementById('id'));
```

All because there is no way jQuery/Sizzle can out-do a native method, and it also means you avoid any string parsing on jQuery/Sizzle's part. It's no where near as neat as it's jQuery counterpart though, and probably wont gain that much speed increase, but it is worth mentioning as an optimisation. You could do the following if you were to use ids often.

```
jQuery.byid = function(id){
  return jQuery(document.getElementById(id))
};

$.byid('elementid');
```

The above would be slightly slower that my previous example, but should still out-do jQuery.

Comment: I haven't seen the `.pushStack` method before, do you know the difference difference between it and `.add`?

Comment: Have extended my answer to answer that question ;)

Comment: Thanks, what your saying makes sense except that why would it then be faster to search for multiple elements in the same selector (`$("#Div0,#Div1 ,#Div2"))?

Comment: Faster than what, doing them each separately? because you are cutting down on function calls mainly. Parsing the string you give - as an example - would be far quicker than calling several functions in a row. A function call is actually quite expensive compared to many other operations. Esp. in this situation as jQuery would probably pass it's selector through to Sizzle even if it's singular or multiple - so '#DIV0' or '#DIV0, #DIV1' would get treated the same initially (there wouldn't be much speed increase for singular selectors comapred to a small number of multiple). Hope that makes sense?

Comment: @Jasper no worries at all :) it's always good to discover new method calls -- `.pushStack` has helped me out quite a few times.

Comment: @pebbl Messing with strings can be slower than running function calls (all about the browser): `$(".some-class > .some-other-class")` will run slower than `$('.some-class').children('.some-other-class')`. Here is a JSPerf I setup a while ago to test this: http://jsperf.com/jquery-function-selectors-vs-strings

Comment: Yes, that is true - but I'm talking about `$(".some-class"); $('.other-class');` which will be slower that `$(".some-class, .other-class")` - purely because one $ function call is quite expensive. What you recommend is definitely the better option for modern browsers however :) most likely because Sizzle can use quicker native functions. When dealing with jQuery though we aren't just comparing a singular function call to something else - as it has many internal functions it uses... I should have made that cleared in what I stated. good point.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are selecting by ID, jQuery (or sizzle, i forget) is skipping ahead to the faster document.getElementById() in this case. You may get different results when using classes, however even then it may vary by browser.

You could make your testing easier using something like http://jsperf.com/

Comment: I haven't set up any tests on [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/) yet, but I actually just ran the same set of tests using just class selectors ($(".div1")` etc.) and besides that again the context isn't speeding it up it's surprisingly faster the the selection by ID.

Comment: It shouldn't be making much of a difference at all. It's a micro optimization. The difference between the two *should* be very small.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using #elementid attribute to perform the tests.

Remember that an **ID**  in a HTML page is supposed to be Unique. So this will not make a difference if you give it a context or not when searching for ID..

This test might make more sense if you are trying to target elements with classes or the element tag themselves.

`$('.mydiv' , $('#innerDiv'))` might be faster than   `$('.mydiv')`

Comment: I realized that the `ID` is supposed to be unique (and is the fastest kind of selection), but what I thought was that by passing in the `context` the search would start at a *lower lever* in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to benefit with context when you use an id since that is highly optimized in the browser.

With a id you can call out and say hey. A non programming example, you are in a room of people, you yell out a name, the person answers.

Now lets look at context. Lets say you know the name is a mans name so you separate the room into men and women. You than ask the group of men for their name. One extra step for something that is rather easy.

You will benefit when you are looking up specific things like attributes. Something that is harder for the browser to look up and is not highly optimized. Say you are looking for an input that has a specific attribute. It would be better to reference an element you know that contains it so it does not have to search every input on the page.

Now the fun part is the context selector is slower. It is better to use find. Why? It has to deal with the creation of multiple jQuery objects. :)

So instead of

```
    $('.myClass', dvCnt).text('Test');
```

do

```
    $(dvCnt).find('.myClass').text('Test');
```

if you are doing multiple look ups, it is better to store the first one into a variable

```
    var myDiv = $(dvCnt)
    myDiv.find('.myClass1').text('Test');
    myDiv.find('.myClass2').text('Test');
```

But now with jQuery doing to querySelector, these optimizations are a smaller deal unless you are using the made up jQuery selectors that querySelector does not support. For browsers that do not support querySelector, the context is important.

Comment: I didn't expect to gain to much with such a small DOM, but I didn't think it would be slower then without it. As for using `.find()` internally jQuery translates a call with the context passed in to one using find.

Comment: @Jack I think what epascarello is getting at is the conversion of a normal dom element `dvCnt` to `$(dvCnt)` will cause a performance hit - especially if done over and over again - with `.find` this isn't usually an issue due to the fact it forces you to pass your context element first and then work on from there. Also in his first example both `$('.myClass'` and `, dvCnt)` will cause a jQuery object to be created - in the second `.find('.myClass')` does not. Basically it is always good practice - as he states - to store your elements as variables, prewrapped with jQuery if needed ;)