# Which one is the better way for performance to set a hover event on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, jquery-selectors

Which one is the better way for performance to set a **hover event** on a `div` with `class` 'con'?
Is there any difference?

1. `$('.con').hover(func(){});`
2. `$('.content0.content.%etc%.con').hover(func(){});`
3. `var con = $('.con'); con.hover(func(){});`

   ```
   <script>
       $('.con').hover(func(){});
   </script>

   <div class="content0">
       <div class="content">
           <div class="fl grad">
               <div class="fl bor_rad bor_gray adver1">
                   <div class="clear">
                       <div class="fl left_ot">
                           <div class="bor_orang h150">
                               <div class="w130 bgfff txc pab10 con">
                                   <a href="#" class="ankor_cont bor_bot_bl w80 ot_top">More</a>
                               </div>
                               <div class="w130 bgfff txc pab10 con">
                                   <a href="#" class="ankor_cont bor_bot_bl w80 ot_top">More</a>
                               </div>
                               <div class="w130 bgfff txc pab10 con">
                                   <a href="#" class="ankor_cont bor_bot_bl w80 ot_top">More</a>
                               </div>
                           </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no significant difference between the three ways you listed, provided the two different selectors you've given select the same elements.

Note that the element lookup is done **once**, when you do the `$("selector here")` part. It's not repeated when the hover occurs.

---

Side note: Probably 95% of what I've seen people do in `hover` event handlers can, on modern browsers (e.g., not IE7 and earlier), be better achieved with CSS using the `:hover` pseudoclass. The other 5% can't, and you haven't said what you're doing and it may well be in that 5%, but I thought I'd point it out... :-)

Comment: Thank you, but what is the better way for tasks where the selector above occurs many times?

Comment: @user1312750: If you had the code in a loop, or if you had code doing `$("selector here")` in a `mousemove` handler, etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
 1. $('.con').hover(func(){});
 2.   $('.content0.content.%etc%.con').hover(func(){}); var con =
 3.   $('.con'); con.hover(func(){});
```

all three work but they take time

because every time **[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)** search in all document[(DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference) then come to your selector

so use **[context](http://api.jquery.com/context/)** by this we tell in jQuery that search not in all document  but search form this element like below..
**in your html**

```
<div class="content0">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="fl grad">
            <div class="fl bor_rad bor_gray adver1">
                <div class="clear">
                    <div class="fl left_ot">
                        <div class="bor_orang h150">
                            <div class="w130 bgfff txc pab10 con">
                                <a href="#" class="ankor_cont bor_bot_bl w80 ot_top">More</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w130 bgfff txc pab10 con">
                                <a href="#" class="ankor_cont bor_bot_bl w80 ot_top">More</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="w130 bgfff txc pab10 con">
                                <a href="#" class="ankor_cont bor_bot_bl w80 ot_top">More</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

now if you write

```
$('.con').hover(func(){});
```

then it reach your selector by following way

first go to

```
document
     |
   body
     |
   content0(class)
     |
   content (class)
     |....
    ...
    then at last your selector '.con'
```

so it will take time
    to get better result define **[context](http://api.jquery.com/context/)** by this it know from where it search your selector like

```
 $('.con','.content0').hover(func(){});
```

now it reach your selector by following way

first go to

```
   content0(class)
    ....
    ...
    then at last your selector '.con'
```

Context really helps when you have a much larger DOM that you are searching through. Searching for IDs is already very fast and context doesn't really help that much in that case. Where context can really make a difference is when you are selecting by tag name or class.

Try testing like this: http://jsbin.com/aciji4/4

you can really see the timing get better for context when you bump up number of items in the DOM like this: http://jsbin.com/aciji4/6

reference [Performance of jQuery selector with context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421782/performance-of-jquery-selector-with-context/15665446#15665446)

Comment: No, `$('.con', '.content0')` is not faster than `$('.con')` (slower, more likely). When you do `$('.con', '.content0')`, jQuery converts that into `$('.content0').find('.con')`. The first part `$('.content0')` takes **just as long** as `$('.con')`. Then you have the added time to look through those elements and find the `.con` elements within them.

Comment: Proof: http://jsperf.com/extra-context-is-useless As you can see, adding extra context just slows it down (nearly doubling the time it takes). Context is only useful if you can **reuse** it, so the code `$('.con', '.content0')` will *always* be slower than `$('.con')`. If you had `var context = $('.content');` and then *repeatedly* did `context.find('.con')`, you might get some benefit.