# Using this with pseudo selectors jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, this, pseudo-class

I'd like to know if there is a way to use `this` with CSS pseudo selectors - (AKA nested elements) in jQuery. Here's what it might look like.

```
    $('#element').click(function(){
        $(this' .nested').css('height','100px');
    });
```

But this isn't how the syntax works. I'd just like to know how it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `find()` instead. Example:

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.nested').css('height','100px');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a million. This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

when you use $(this) use .find() to get the element you want
like this

```
$('#element').click(function(){    
   $(this).find('.nested').css('height','100px');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either use .css() or also toggle a class in jQuery and set the CSS property inside your CSS file which It's usually more performing and reusable.

```
$('#element').click(function(){    
   $(this).find('.nested').css('height','100px');
});
```

or also

```
$('#element').click(function(){    
   $(this).find('.nested').toggleClass('height-nested');
});
```

**CSS**

```
.height-nested{
   height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    $('.nested',this).css('height','100px');
});
```

Or

```
$('#element').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.nested').css('height','100px');
});
```

Comment: I liked your answer , just to add performance stuff , first is slow respect to second http://stackoverflow.com/a/8083631/1018054