# How to improve loading times on a large object reference in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, object-reference

This is the code:

```
mainobject = $("#MainObject");
topBasis = mainobject.offset().top;
mainHeight = mainobject.height();
leftBasis = mainobject.offset().left;
mainWidth = mainobject.width();
```

But because of the fact that the MainObject is really large it takes a few seconds to execute this piece of code.
Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: `MainObject is really large` ? How does that make a difference ?

Comment: There must be something else which is causing the issues..can you share a live demo where one could re-produce this issue..

Comment: you can `detach()` object before perform operation if it is really large looping on object. I don't think so it takes too time may be so other issue.

Comment: No, by logging the time I have found that this piece of code is the problem, MainObject is about 5000 in lenght in minimum so because of that it takes a few seconds to load the whole object into mainobject

Answer (score 0):

You could add that piece of code right before closing the `body` tag. This way, you win a couple of seconds because while the page loads, your script runs in the background.

You could read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421782/performance-of-jquery-selector-with-context?lq=1) post for a way to improve the performance. What I would recommend, is some sort of pagination. You bring what you expect the user to request and this way, for example once every 5-10 objects, you bring others, but for some time, you will have them already.

Comment: This code runs a lot of times, even after the page has loaded completely, so this would only help at the start

Comment: Does it always bring a new object? You could cache it to save time like that.

Comment: I would, but the object changes all the time and it needs to be visible

Comment: Tried the link I gave you to improve performance?
You could try getting each element using an asynchronous call, to parallelize it, but I do not think this will improve much.

Comment: Yes I have read it but I cant really find anything to improve my code.
what do you mean by your second part of your comment?

Comment: Your code is executed line by line.
If you could force the browser to do them in parallel, than you would win some time.

Comment: And how could i do this?

Comment: It depends way too much if you can send parts of the object, if you can set them without having a problem after that. I highly doubt you can get a big improvement.